# Excel to send emails

Tags: vba, excel, email

Hi I have an excel that sends an email with all rows with the same name in column (hotel) from sheet list.

I wanted the user to have the possibility to choose which columns are sent and how the data is ordered, in sheet: menu. Also the user can define a text in the body before and after the table and the subject of the email.

[image]

The macro was working well but now I want to use column "Operador" in the email and the email sent isnt sending well, Operador doesnt have right value and dates are in another format:
 [image]

The excel file is here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5b2wc3w5db2m01/Email%20das%20reservas.xlsm?dl=1

The VBA is here:

```
Sub btnSendMails()

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim strTo As String
Dim strCc As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strBody As String
Dim shtMain As Worksheet
Dim shtMails As Worksheet
Dim shtMenu As Worksheet
Dim shtTmp  As Worksheet
Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim iLastColumn As Integer
Dim sHotelName As String
Dim iCl As Integer
Dim myArr() As String
Dim iColumn As Integer
Dim iRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim iHotel As Integer
Set shtMain = Sheets("list")
Set shtMails = Sheets("hotels")
Set shtMenu = Sheets("menu")
Set shtTmp = Sheets("tmp")
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim iPos As Integer
iLastRow = shtMain.Cells(shtMain.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
iLastColumn = shtMenu.Cells(3, shtMenu.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
ilastrowmail = shtMails.Cells(shtMails.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

shtMain.Range("A1:AO" & iLastRow).Sort key1:=shtMain.Range("B1:N" & iLastRow), _
   order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes


ReDim Preserve myArr(5)

j = 0
shtTmp.Cells.ClearContents

For iCl = 2 To 41
    If shtMain.Cells(1, iCl) = "Hotel" Then
        iHotel = iCl
        Exit For
    End If
Next iCl
For i = 3 To iLastColumn
    myArr(j) = UCase(shtMenu.Cells(3, i))
    j = j + 1
    ReDim Preserve myArr(j)
Next i
For i = 0 To UBound(myArr)
    shtTmp.Cells(1, i + 1) = myArr(i)
Next i

For i = 2 To iLastRow
    If InStr(shtMain.Cells(i, iHotel), "(") = 0 Then
        iPos = 50
    Else
        iPos = InStr(shtMain.Cells(i, iHotel), "(")
    End If
    sHotelName = Left(shtMain.Cells(i, iHotel), iPos - 2)
    iRow = 2
    For j = i To iLastRow
        iColumn = 1
        For iCl = 1 To 41
            If IsInArray(UCase(shtMain.Cells(1, iCl)), myArr) Then
                shtTmp.Cells(1, iColumn) = shtMain.Cells(1, iCl)
                shtTmp.Cells(iRow, iColumn) = shtMain.Cells(j, iCl)
                If shtTmp.Cells(1, iColumn) = "Obs" Then shtTmp.Cells(iRow, iColumn) = shtTmp.Cells(iRow, iColumn) & vbNewLine
                iColumn = iColumn + 1
            End If
        Next iCl
        shtTmp.Cells(iRow, 1) = sHotelName
        On Error GoTo Resume1
        If Left(shtMain.Cells(j + 1, iHotel), iPos - 2) = sHotelName Then
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Else
Resume1:
            For r = 2 To ilastrowmail
                If UCase(sHotelName) = UCase(shtMails.Cells(r, 3)) Then
                    strTo = shtMails.Cells(r, 4)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next r
            If strTo = "" Then
                MsgBox "Email not found for " & sHotelName & vbNewLine & "Macro will resume."
            Else
                Set rng = shtTmp.Range(shtTmp.Cells(1, 1), shtTmp.Cells(iRow, UBound(myArr)))
                strSubject = shtMenu.Cells(13, 3)
                strBody = shtMenu.Cells(7, 3) & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & shtMenu.Cells(10, 3)
                Call createMail(objOutlook, strTo, strSubject, strBody)
            End If
            strTo = ""
            shtTmp.Cells.ClearContents
            For r = 0 To UBound(myArr)
                shtTmp.Cells(1, r + 1) = myArr(r)
            Next r
            i = j
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

shtTmp.Select


If shtMenu.Cells(15, 6) <> "x" Then
Exit Sub
End If

Set shtTmp = Sheets("tmpCar")
Dim iRentacar As Integer
Set shtMails = Sheets("rentacar")
iLastRow = shtMain.Cells(shtMain.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
iLastColumn = shtMenu.Cells(17, shtMenu.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
ilastrowmail = shtMails.Cells(shtMails.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

shtMain.Range("A1:AO" & iLastRow).Sort key1:=shtMain.Range("B1:N" & iLastRow), _
   order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

Erase myArr
ReDim myArr(1)

j = 0
shtTmp.Cells.ClearContents

For i = 3 To iLastColumn
    myArr(j) = UCase(shtMenu.Cells(17, i))
    Debug.Print myArr(j)
    j = j + 1
    ReDim Preserve myArr(j)
Next i
For i = 0 To UBound(myArr)
    shtTmp.Cells(1, i + 1) = myArr(i)
Next i

For iCl = 2 To 41
    If shtMain.Cells(1, iCl) = "Rent a car" Then
        iRentacar = iCl
        Exit For
    End If
Next iCl

For i = 2 To iLastRow
    If shtMain.Cells(i, iRentacar) <> "" And shtMain.Cells(i, iRentacar) <> 0 Then
        If InStr(shtMain.Cells(j + 1, iHotel), "(") = 0 Then
            iPos = 50
        Else
            iPos = InStr(shtMain.Cells(i, iHotel), "(")
        End If
        sHotelName = Left(shtMain.Cells(i, iHotel), iPos - 2)
        iRow = 2
        For j = i To iLastRow
            iColumn = 1
            For iCl = 1 To 41
                If IsInArray(UCase(shtMain.Cells(1, iCl)), myArr) Then
                    shtTmp.Cells(1, iColumn) = shtMain.Cells(1, iCl)
                    shtTmp.Cells(iRow, iColumn) = shtMain.Cells(j, iCl)
                    If shtTmp.Cells(1, iColumn) = "Obs" Then shtTmp.Cells(iRow, iColumn) = shtTmp.Cells(iRow, iColumn) & vbNewLine
                    iColumn = iColumn + 1
                End If
            Next iCl
            shtTmp.Cells(iRow, 1) = sHotelName
            On Error GoTo Resume2

            If Left(shtMain.Cells(j + 1, iHotel), iPos - 2) = sHotelName Then
                iRow = iRow + 1
            Else
Resume2:
                For r = 2 To ilastrowmail
                    If shtMain.Cells(i, iRentacar + 1) = shtMails.Cells(r, 2) Then
                        strTo = shtMails.Cells(r, 3)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next r
                If strTo = "" Then
                    MsgBox "Rent a Car service not found for " & sHotelName & vbNewLine & "Macro will resume."
                Else
                    Set rng = shtTmp.Range(shtTmp.Cells(1, 1), shtTmp.Cells(iRow, UBound(myArr)))
                    strSubject = shtMenu.Cells(27, 3)
                    strBody = shtMenu.Cells(21, 3) & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & shtMenu.Cells(24, 3)
                    Call createMail(objOutlook, strTo, strSubject, strBody)
                End If
                strTo = ""
                shtTmp.Cells.ClearContents
                For r = 0 To UBound(myArr)
                    shtTmp.Cells(1, r + 1) = myArr(r)
                Next r
                i = j
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i
shtTmp.Select

End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = False
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        If stringToBeFound = arr(i) Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function

Sub createMail(objOutlook As Outlook.Application, strTo As String, strSubject As String, strBody As String)

Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)


With objMail
    .To = strTo
    .Subject = strSubject
    .HTMLBody = Replace(strBody, "0in", "1in")
    .Save
    ' If you want to send:
    '.Send
End With

Set objMail = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

What I tried was to detect the position of hotel column, so compared to code I had before I added a variable iHotel and used it in the several iteractions..

Thank you in advance!!

NOTE:Also we have 2 columns: rent-a-car and service, (in the data list table) if it has a value in that cell (rent-a-car) we want a rule that, that rows could be sent to the hotel and send a different email to another email based on a value in another cell (service). We have the list of services and respective email and columns for rent-a-car email.

Comment: Please add the relevant code parts into your question and format it as code block. Most people won't download macro enabled files form a unknown source and also this question will be useless for further readers when the download disappears. Also show what you already tried to achieve your goal, because most people will kindly assist you in finishing your code but most will not do all the work for you.

Comment: Added, hope it is enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly then simply replace your code with the following and it should show the dates as you expect:

```
Sub btnSendMails()
Dim strTo As String, strCc As String, strSubject As String, strBody As String, sHotelName As String, myArr() As String, DateValue As String, DateValue2 As String, DateValue3 As String
Dim iLastRow As Long, iLastColumn As Long, iColumn As Long, iRow As Long, iCl As Long, iHotel As Long, iPos As Long, i As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim shtMain As Worksheet: Set shtMain = Sheets("list")
Dim shtMails As Worksheet: Set shtMails = Sheets("hotels")
Dim shtMenu As Worksheet: Set shtMenu = Sheets("menu")
Dim shtTmp  As Worksheet: Set shtTmp = Sheets("tmp")
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

iLastRow = shtMain.Cells(shtMain.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
iLastColumn = shtMenu.Cells(3, shtMenu.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
ilastrowmail = shtMails.Cells(shtMails.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To iLastRow
    DateValue = shtMain.Cells(i, 3)
    shtMain.Cells(i, 3).NumberFormat = "@"
    shtMain.Cells(i, 3).Value = DateValue
    DateValue2 = shtMain.Cells(i, 9)
    shtMain.Cells(i, 9).NumberFormat = "@"
    shtMain.Cells(i, 9).Value = DateValue2
    DateValue3 = shtMain.Cells(i, 23)
    shtMain.Cells(i, 23).NumberFormat = "@"
    shtMain.Cells(i, 23).Value = DateValue3
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

shtMain.Range("A1:AO" & iLastRow).Sort key1:=shtMain.Range("B1:N" & iLastRow), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

ReDim Preserve myArr(5)

j = 0
shtTmp.Cells.ClearContents

For iCl = 2 To 41
    If shtMain.Cells(1, iCl) = "Hotel" Then
        iHotel = iCl
        Exit For
    End If
Next iCl

For i = 3 To iLastColumn
    myArr(j) = UCase(shtMenu.Cells(3, i))
    j = j + 1
    ReDim Preserve myArr(j)
Next i

For i = 0 To UBound(myArr)
    shtTmp.Cells(1, i + 1) = myArr(i)
Next i

For i = 2 To iLastRow
    If InStr(shtMain.Cells(i, iHotel), "(") = 0 Then
        iPos = 50
    Else
        iPos = InStr(shtMain.Cells(i, iHotel), "(")
    End If
    sHotelName = Left(shtMain.Cells(i, iHotel), iPos - 2)
    iRow = 2
    For j = i To iLastRow
        iColumn = 1
        For iCl = 1 To 41
            If IsInArray(UCase(shtMain.Cells(1, iCl)), myArr) Then
                shtTmp.Cells(1, iColumn) = shtMain.Cells(1, iCl)
                shtTmp.Cells(iRow, iColumn) = shtMain.Cells(j, iCl)
                If shtTmp.Cells(1, iColumn) = "Obs" Then shtTmp.Cells(iRow, iColumn) = shtTmp.Cells(iRow, iColumn) & vbNewLine
                iColumn = iColumn + 1
            End If
        Next iCl

        On Error GoTo Resume1
        If Left(shtMain.Cells(j + 1, iHotel), iPos - 2) = sHotelName Then
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Else
Resume1:
            For r = 2 To ilastrowmail
                If UCase(sHotelName) = UCase(shtMails.Cells(r, 3)) Then
                    strTo = shtMails.Cells(r, 4)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next r
            If strTo = "" Then
                MsgBox "Email not found for " & sHotelName & vbNewLine & "Macro will resume."
            Else
                Set rng = shtTmp.Range(shtTmp.Cells(1, 1), shtTmp.Cells(iRow, UBound(myArr)))
                strSubject = shtMenu.Cells(13, 3)
                strBody = shtMenu.Cells(7, 3) & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & shtMenu.Cells(10, 3)
                Call createMail(objOutlook, strTo, strSubject, strBody)
            End If
            strTo = ""
            shtTmp.Cells.ClearContents
            For r = 0 To UBound(myArr)
                shtTmp.Cells(1, r + 1) = myArr(r)
            Next r
            i = j
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

If shtMenu.Cells(15, 6) <> "x" Then
Exit Sub
End If

Set shtTmp = Sheets("tmpCar")
Dim iRentacar As Long
Set shtMails = Sheets("rentacar")
iLastRow = shtMain.Cells(shtMain.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
iLastColumn = shtMenu.Cells(17, shtMenu.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
ilastrowmail = shtMails.Cells(shtMails.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

shtMain.Range("A1:AO" & iLastRow).Sort key1:=shtMain.Range("B1:N" & iLastRow), _
   order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

Erase myArr
ReDim myArr(1)

j = 0
shtTmp.Cells.ClearContents

For i = 3 To iLastColumn
    myArr(j) = UCase(shtMenu.Cells(17, i))
    Debug.Print myArr(j)
    j = j + 1
    ReDim Preserve myArr(j)
Next i

For i = 0 To UBound(myArr)
    shtTmp.Cells(1, i + 1) = myArr(i)
Next i

For iCl = 2 To 41
    If shtMain.Cells(1, iCl) = "Rent a car" Then
        iRentacar = iCl
        Exit For
    End If
Next iCl

For i = 2 To iLastRow
    If shtMain.Cells(i, iRentacar) <> "" And shtMain.Cells(i, iRentacar) <> 0 Then
        If InStr(shtMain.Cells(j + 1, iHotel), "(") = 0 Then
            iPos = 50
        Else
            iPos = InStr(shtMain.Cells(i, iHotel), "(")
        End If
        sHotelName = Left(shtMain.Cells(i, iHotel), iPos - 2)
        iRow = 2
        For j = i To iLastRow
            iColumn = 1
            For iCl = 1 To 41
                If IsInArray(UCase(shtMain.Cells(1, iCl)), myArr) Then
                    shtTmp.Cells(1, iColumn) = shtMain.Cells(1, iCl)
                    shtTmp.Cells(iRow, iColumn) = shtMain.Cells(j, iCl)
                    If shtTmp.Cells(1, iColumn) = "Obs" Then shtTmp.Cells(iRow, iColumn) = shtTmp.Cells(iRow, iColumn) & vbNewLine
                    iColumn = iColumn + 1
                End If
            Next iCl
            shtTmp.Cells(iRow, 1) = sHotelName
            On Error GoTo Resume2

            If Left(shtMain.Cells(j + 1, iHotel), iPos - 2) = sHotelName Then
                iRow = iRow + 1
            Else
Resume2:
                For r = 2 To ilastrowmail
                    If shtMain.Cells(i, iRentacar + 1) = shtMails.Cells(r, 2) Then
                        strTo = shtMails.Cells(r, 3)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next r
                If strTo = "" Then
                    MsgBox "Rent a Car service not found for " & sHotelName & vbNewLine & "Macro will resume."
                Else
                    Set rng = shtTmp.Range(shtTmp.Cells(1, 1), shtTmp.Cells(iRow, UBound(myArr)))
                    strSubject = shtMenu.Cells(27, 3)
                    strBody = shtMenu.Cells(21, 3) & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & shtMenu.Cells(24, 3)
                    Call createMail(objOutlook, strTo, strSubject, strBody)
                End If
                strTo = ""
                shtTmp.Cells.ClearContents
                For r = 0 To UBound(myArr)
                    shtTmp.Cells(1, r + 1) = myArr(r)
                Next r
                i = j
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i
End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = False
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        If stringToBeFound = arr(i) Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function

Sub createMail(objOutlook As Outlook.Application, strTo As String, strSubject As String, strBody As String)

Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With objMail
    .To = strTo
    .Subject = strSubject
    .HTMLBody = Replace(strBody, "0in", "1in")
    .Save
    ' If you want to send:
    '.Send
End With

Set objMail = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

I've simply added a loop to format your dates as strings, so that when you attach them to the email the come in the right format. The code I added is:

```
For i = 2 To iLastRow
    DateValue = shtMain.Cells(i, 3)
    shtMain.Cells(i, 3).NumberFormat = "@"
    shtMain.Cells(i, 3).Value = DateValue
    DateValue2 = shtMain.Cells(i, 9)
    shtMain.Cells(i, 9).NumberFormat = "@"
    shtMain.Cells(i, 9).Value = DateValue2
    DateValue3 = shtMain.Cells(i, 23)
    shtMain.Cells(i, 23).NumberFormat = "@"
    shtMain.Cells(i, 23).Value = DateValue3
Next i
```

Also to fix the Operator issue, you simply had to remove the following line of code:

```
shtTmp.Cells(iRow, 1) = sHotelName
```

Comment: OK thanks! But the problem with column "Operador" still happens. It is being filled with the data from Hotel column... – Mary 7 mins ago

Comment: @Mary updated my answer, it should work for Operator now too. :)

Comment: Thank you! related to the dates format issue, this solution allows me if I change dates columns order in email  it works the same?

Comment: I have another question related to the order of the columns in the email I tried a solution but it is very slow.. May I do the question in another thread?

Comment: @Mary If you change the order of your columns, you might have to format your dates again, unless you change the columns after you run the code as in my answer...

Comment: I was talking about changing the order of dates in the email sent and not in the list sheet..

Comment: Yes then you can change them without losing the formatting.. :)