# Order columns when sending email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have Excel code that sends an email with all rows with the same name in column (hotel) from sheet list.

I want to choose which columns are sent and how the data is ordered, in sheet menu.

As explained here:
[Excel to send emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705516/excel-to-send-emails/48705915?noredirect=1#comment84419832_48705915)

The way it is programmed does not allow ordering the columns in the email, or at least it only orders by the order columns appear in the sheet list.

I tried a solution but it is much slower:

The whole code:

```
Sub btnSendMails()

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim strTo As String
Dim strCc As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strBody As String
Dim shtMain As Worksheet
Dim shtMails As Worksheet
Dim shtMenu As Worksheet
Dim shtTmp  As Worksheet
Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim iLastColumn As Integer
Dim sHotelName As String
Dim iCl As Integer
Dim myArr() As String
Dim iColumn As Integer
Dim iRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Set shtMain = Sheets("list")
Set shtMails = Sheets("hotels")
Set shtMenu = Sheets("menu")
Set shtTmp = Sheets("tmp")
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
iLastRow = shtMain.Cells(shtMain.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
iLastColumn = shtMenu.Cells(3, shtMenu.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
ilastrowmail = shtMails.Cells(shtMails.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

shtMain.Range("A1:AO" & iLastRow).Sort key1:=shtMain.Range("B1:N" & iLastRow), _
   order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

ReDim Preserve myArr(5)

j = 0
shtTmp.Cells.ClearContents

For i = 3 To iLastColumn
    myArr(j) = shtMenu.Cells(3, i)
    j = j + 1
    ReDim Preserve myArr(j)
Next i
For i = 0 To UBound(myArr)
    shtTmp.Cells(1, i + 1) = myArr(i)
Next i

For i = 2 To iLastRow
    sHotelName = Left(shtMain.Cells(i, 2), InStr(shtMain.Cells(i, 2), "(") - 2)
    iRow = 2
    For j = i To iLastRow
        iColumn = 1
        For iCl = 2 To 41
            If IsInArray(shtMain.Cells(1, iCl), myArr) Then
                shtTmp.Cells(1, iColumn) = shtMain.Cells(1, iCl)
                shtTmp.Cells(iRow, iColumn) = shtMain.Cells(j, iCl)
                If shtTmp.Cells(1, iColumn) = "Obs" Then shtTmp.Cells(iRow, iColumn) = shtTmp.Cells(iRow, iColumn) & vbNewLine
                iColumn = iColumn + 1
            End If
        Next iCl
        shtTmp.Cells(iRow, 1) = sHotelName
        On Error GoTo Resume1
        If Left(shtMain.Cells(j + 1, 2), InStr(shtMain.Cells(j + 1, 2), "(") - 2) = sHotelName Then
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Else
Resume1:
            For r = 2 To ilastrowmail
                If UCase(sHotelName) = shtMails.Cells(r, 3) Then
                    strTo = shtMails.Cells(r, 4)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next r
            If strTo = "" Then
                MsgBox "Email not found for " & sHotelName & vbNewLine & "Macro will resume."
            Else
                shtTmp.Select
                On Error GoTo Skipit
                HeaderNames = myArr
                For l = 0 To UBound(HeaderNames)
                    Columns(Rows(1).Find(HeaderNames(l), , xlValues, xlWhole).Column).Cut
                    If Rows(1).Find(HeaderNames(l), , xlValues, xlWhole).Column = l + 1 Then
                    Else
                        Columns(l + 1).Insert
                    End If
Skipit:
                Next
                Set rng = shtTmp.Range(shtTmp.Cells(1, 1), shtTmp.Cells(iRow, UBound(myArr) + 1))
                strSubject = shtMenu.Cells(13, 3)
                strBody = shtMenu.Cells(7, 3) & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & shtMenu.Cells(10, 3)
                Call createMail(objOutlook, strTo, strSubject, strBody)
            End If
            strTo = ""
            shtTmp.Cells.ClearContents
            For r = 0 To UBound(myArr)
                shtTmp.Cells(1, r + 1) = myArr(r)
            Next r
            i = j
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

If shtMenu.Cells(15, 6) <> "x" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set shtTmp = Sheets("tmpCar")
Dim iRentacar As Integer
Set shtMails = Sheets("rentacar")
iLastRow = shtMain.Cells(shtMain.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
iLastColumn = shtMenu.Cells(17, shtMenu.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
ilastrowmail = shtMails.Cells(shtMails.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

shtMain.Range("A1:AO" & iLastRow).Sort key1:=shtMain.Range("B1:N" & iLastRow), _
   order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

ReDim myArr(5)

j = 0
shtTmp.Cells.ClearContents

For i = 3 To iLastColumn
    myArr(j) = shtMenu.Cells(17, i)
    j = j + 1
    ReDim Preserve myArr(j)
Next i
For i = 0 To UBound(myArr)
    shtTmp.Cells(1, i + 1) = myArr(i)
Next i

For iCl = 2 To 41
    If shtMain.Cells(1, iCl) = "Rent a car" Then
        iRentacar = iCl
        Exit For
    End If
Next iCl
shtTmp.Select
For i = 2 To iLastRow
    If shtMain.Cells(i, iRentacar) <> "" And shtMain.Cells(i, iRentacar) <> 0 Then
        sHotelName = Left(shtMain.Cells(i, 2), InStr(shtMain.Cells(i, 2), "(") - 2)
        iRow = 2
        For j = i To iLastRow
            iColumn = 1
            For iCl = 2 To 41
                If IsInArray(shtMain.Cells(1, iCl), myArr) Then
                    shtTmp.Cells(1, iColumn) = shtMain.Cells(1, iCl)
                    shtTmp.Cells(iRow, iColumn) = shtMain.Cells(j, iCl)
                    If shtTmp.Cells(1, iColumn) = "Obs" Then shtTmp.Cells(iRow, iColumn) = shtTmp.Cells(iRow, iColumn) & vbNewLine
                    iColumn = iColumn + 1
                End If
            Next iCl
            shtTmp.Cells(iRow, 1) = sHotelName
            On Error GoTo Resume2
            If Left(shtMain.Cells(j + 1, 2), InStr(shtMain.Cells(j + 1, 2), "(") - 2) = sHotelName Then
                iRow = iRow + 1
            Else
Resume2:
                For r = 2 To ilastrowmail
                    If shtMain.Cells(i, iRentacar + 1) = shtMails.Cells(r, 2) Then
                        strTo = shtMails.Cells(r, 3)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next r
                If strTo = "" Then
                    MsgBox "Email not found for " & sHotelName & vbNewLine & "Macro will resume."
                Else
                On Error GoTo Skipit2
                HeaderNames = myArr
                    For l = 0 To UBound(HeaderNames)
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                        Columns(Rows(1).Find(HeaderNames(l), , xlValues, xlWhole).Column).Cut
                        If l + 1 = Rows(1).Find(HeaderNames(l), , xlValues, xlWhole).Column Then
                        Else
                        Columns(l + 1).Insert
                        End If
Skipit2:
                    Next
                    Set rng = shtTmp.Range(shtTmp.Cells(1, 1), shtTmp.Cells(iRow, UBound(myArr) + 1))
                    strSubject = shtMenu.Cells(27, 3)
                    strBody = shtMenu.Cells(21, 3) & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & shtMenu.Cells(24, 3)
                    Call createMail(objOutlook, strTo, strSubject, strBody)
                End If
                strTo = ""
                shtTmp.Cells.ClearContents
                For r = 0 To UBound(myArr)
                    shtTmp.Cells(1, r + 1) = myArr(r)
                Next r
                i = j
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i
shtTmp.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function

Sub createMail(objOutlook As Outlook.Application, strTo As String, strSubject As String, strBody As String)

Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With objMail
    .To = strTo
    .Subject = strSubject
    .HTMLBody = Replace(strBody, "0in", "1in")
    .Save
    ' If you want to send:
    '.Send
End With

Set objMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

The main difference is this bit of code:

```
shtTmp.Select
On Error GoTo Skipit
HeaderNames = myArr
For l = 0 To UBound(HeaderNames)
    Columns(Rows(1).Find(HeaderNames(l), , xlValues, xlWhole).Column).Cut
    If Rows(1).Find(HeaderNames(l), , xlValues, xlWhole).Column = l + 1 Then
    Else
        Columns(l + 1).Insert
    End If
Skipit:
Next
Set rng = shtTmp.Range(shtTmp.Cells(1, 1), shtTmp.Cells(iRow, UBound(myArr) + 1))
```

Is their anyway I can do this in a quicker fashion?

Comment: Have you tried [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba), it's a stackexchange dedicated to improving working existing code.